# Passing form input data to post request

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

I'm very new to Python/Django and trying to create search box which grabs the data from an API and returns the result on HTML. Just like any other search engine does.

I have to passed the token via headers. This is my current code.

url.py

```
    urlpatterns = [
        url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
        url(r'^$',views.search, name='search'),]
```

form.py

```
from django import forms

class SearchForm(forms.form):
search_company = forms.CharField(label='search_company',max_length=100)
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django import SearchForm

def get_search (request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SearchForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/search.html')
        else:
            form = SearchForm()

        return render(request, "main/search.html")
```

search.html

```
  <form class="col-md-6" action="/search.html/" method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      <label for="search_company">Search Company</label>
      <input type="text" name="search_company">
      <input type="submit" value="ok">
  </form>
```

this is my error in console

```
Performing system checks...

Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f3cc120f0d0>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/venv/HomeBase/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 226, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/venv/HomeBase/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 121, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/venv/HomeBase/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 374, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/venv/HomeBase/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 361, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/venv/HomeBase/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/venv/HomeBase/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 14, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/venv/HomeBase/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 24, in check_resolver
    for pattern in resolver.url_patterns:
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/venv/HomeBase/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/venv/HomeBase/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 313, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/venv/HomeBase/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/venv/HomeBase/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 306, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/venv/HomeBase/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/homebase/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from metaphor import views
  File "/home/lucy/work/homebase/metaphor/views.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django import SearchForm
ImportError: cannot import name 'SearchForm'
```

**edit**: Updated post with new error.

Comment: In your `search` method you call `form.getvalue()`. Where should `form` come from? (Note that the error messages tells you this: "`line 6, in search` `data = form.getvalue('searchbox')` `NameError: name 'form' is not defined`)

Comment: form is in search.html

Comment: Okay, but how is your code supposed to get access to it? Have you [built a form class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#the-django-form-class)?

Comment: No i have not. I am not sure whether that should be the part of model.py or view.py , also is it right way to get value from form field ?  I have read lot of tutorials but it made me confused. I just want to inject data dynamically from the form rather than specified dict.

Comment: It can go anywhere, but a common pattern is to put your forms in a file called `forms.py` beside your `models.py` and `views.py` files. I'm not sure what tutorials you've read, but the official documentation is very good. The [page I linked to in my previous comment](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/) covers basic Django forms from end to end. I recommend you start there.

Comment: Thank you @Chris i didnt knew that type value can be variable {{ }}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136058/discussion-between-robus-and-chris).

Answer (score 1):

> from django import SearchForm
>   ImportError: cannot import name 'SearchForm'

The updated error is because you are trying to import the SearchFrom from the root of the django library.

You need to import your `SearchForm` from your app, so in your `views.py`

```
from django import SearchForm
```

should be something like

```
from myapp.form import SearchForm
```

Also, in Django it is common to call your forms containing file `forms`(plural) instead of `form` (singular), since it can contain multiple forms.

Comment: Any luck so far on your issue?

Comment: nope. both  'from app.name.form import SearchForm' & from .form import SearchForm throws attribute error

Answer (score 0):

The SearchForm is in your django app and not in your django library.

Use from .form import SearchForm

Also, move your else to ( if request.method == POST ), so that the form is sent if method is not post.

And I would suggest you to use reverse() function to resolve url ,

HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('search'))